# TFS 2012 rollback vs permanent delete changeset?

Tags: tfs

If someone accidentally commits gigs (10GB) of music files to TFS is there a way for the admin to actually DELETE a changeset? And no - I don't mean rollback - rollback still keeps the files in history. This is not helpful with 10GB of garbage in the database. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution that worked for me - dump TFS as source control and use Git. The Git integration in the new TFS makes this really easy, especially with a tool like Git-TF (https://gittf.codeplex.com/), which allows you to migrate your full commit history from TFS to Git. Git allows you to rewrite/alter history as required and is all around a more flexible source control system.

Comment: This is pretty much the way Microsoft is going, actually. They keep making so much noise about TFS supporting git I full expect that TFS will drop its source control in favour of being just an ALM package.

Answer (score 1):

You can permanently remove files with

> tf destroy

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I did see that and have used it before but I see no way to operate on a changeset... only files. Is there a way I can select an entire changeset to remove instead of the hundreds of files?

Comment: I think the best way of describing what I want to do is to permanently delete all changes that the changeset made, but retain the HISTORY of any files that were previously there, but NOT in the changeset selected... there are some valid files that were actually overwritten as well and I want to permanently delete all record of the changes to them.