# Understand Rollback Entire changeset in tfs?

Tags: tfs, version-control, changeset

I'm new to TFS. Suppose I have 2 consecutive versions of changeset: 600,601. Nowf if I right click on 601 and choose ***Rollback Entire changeset***, does that mean after that the changeset 601 should be exactly the same as 600?

I ask this because after doing so, I tried comparing the 2 changesets and saw they're still much different. So it's so confusing to me about what *Rollback Entire changeset* did?

Comment: This is a duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664617/tfs-2012-rollback-vs-permanent-delete-changeset which is also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784627/how-to-remove-a-specific-changeset-in-tfs-2010

Comment: @TfsAgent it may be but the original issue of mine is understand how Rollback Entire Changeset works, so it was hard for me to search for those results.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Rollback entire changeset will give you a set of Pending Changes that when checked in will "undo" what was done in changeset 601.

The result is that you will have 3 changesets: 600, 601, 602.  And the resulting state will be the same as after 600.

Comment: so do you mean the changeset itself won't never change? (permanently fixed)? The result (after checked in) will be put in a new changeset (602) and this is exactly the same as 600?

Comment: Yes, the changeset does not change, Rollback entire changeset means rollback the content of the changeset, you will need the changeset to track the changes on the file history.

Comment: @Hopeless - I have just applied my first changeset rollback and yes the original changeset is negated by the application of a follow-on changeset that reverses the original. A Technical Architect might refer to this as a "Compensating Transaction".